# Read the screen and input the commands that shows

Tags: python, power-automate-desktop

I'm learning more about input and reading, and trying to optimize the acting.

All I'm trying is to read something like that:
[Image for reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpF65.png)

To the program read these commands (up, down, left, right) and press the inputs on the keyboard.

Need to select the X and Y area to ready and thats all.

Tried to use PAD, but the OCR reading failure alot on the sequence, like the answer on PAD is
[PAD OCR reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VowhQ.png)
that is the first step, reading the screen. so I'm stuck on the first phase yet

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please review the FAQ on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you have tried so far.  Your current post doesn't really ask a question.  Please clarify your issue/question with as much detail as possible.  For example,  Is it necessary for these inputs to be read via OCR as opposed to being read directly from a text file or other source?

Comment: can't you read it from some file? What modules/tools do you use? Where is your code? We can't see your code, and we can't read in you mind - so we don't know how to help you.

Comment: the only think which I can suggest: doc for OCR Tesseract [Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html). Sometimes OCR may not detect text if it is too small - you may have to resize image.

Comment: OCR is usually the last resort when all else fails. Where does the image come from is it a screen grab of the application you are using or are you specifically trying to read text from an image? if it's from a text file, just read the file, if it's from a terminal just extract the data from the terminal.